# Refresh indicator sometime did not perform the action

Tags: flutter, dart

I have one refresh indicator in which I print something. When I drag the refresh indicator sometimes it prints the statement but sometimes I drag the refresh indicator it just moves up quickly and does not perform anything.
I do not know why this strange behavior or what I am missing.

```
RefreshIndicator(
                  onRefresh: () async {
                      print("I am refresshing the data");
                      await some APi call
                    };
child:Listview.builder();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function and pass it to onRefresh. And In that function, you should perform your task.

```
onRefresh: refreshList 

 Future<Null> refreshList() async{
      await Apicall();
    }
    
    Apicall(){
    //write api call
    }
```

Comment: Does not make any difference.

Comment: what does it change by implementing this way?

Comment: Yes, when you use it with Future then you would see the change.